# JS (jQuery) - If condition - any digit

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements, any, digit

I am trying to achieve the following: I have an element(s) and all of them can have classes assigned to them (some has "a1", some "a2", "a3"... or they can be without class).
I need to check (in condition) if I am dealing with any of "a*"-class element, or with non-"a*"-class element.
Obvious way would be:

```
if (element.prop('class')=='a1' || element.prop('class')=='a2' ||...){ // some action}
```

but since number of different "a" classes is dynamic and can go to high numbers, I would like to test rather for something like this

```
if (element.prop('class')=='a\d'){ // some action}
```

or replacing /d with [0-9]. A have done quite some research on this regular expressions, but haven't find anything suitable neither working.
Is there any preferably Regex-way(or similar) or any alternative to my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has regular expression literals, and you'd want to use the [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
if (/a\d/.test(element.attr('class'))) { 
    // some action
}
```

Side note: `class` is an HTML attribute, not a node property (use `attr` not `prop`)

Comment: Thank you. About the prop vs attr. I read something like attributes are more like default values that, which are used to fill properties of DOM object after page is ready and so there was the recomendation to use prop, since properties are the things that change (when working with DOM objects) and because there are some value, that doesn't rewrite the (default)attribute. So if you do not mind, can you give me some brief clarification.

Comment: @LukášŘádek [`class` is an HTML attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class), so you would use `attr` to get and set it. [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) and [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) are node properties, so you would use `prop` to get and set them. In the case where jQuery can't find a property you ask for, it will automatically search for attributes too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this regex:

```
/(^|\s)a\d/
```

Because it looks for the `a` at the beginning of the string or after a space, so it will work in cases where the element had more than one class specified, like `class="b2 a1"`, but won't accept class names that have other letters before the `a`, like `class="ha1"`.

So:

```
if (/(^|\s)a\d/.test(element.prop('class')) {
```

Note that you don't test against a regex using `==` like you had in your code. You use [regex methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#RegExp_instances-Methods) like [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).

And the regex itself is created either as a regex literal, where you put the expression in between two forward slashes like this:

```
/(^|\s)a\d/
```

Or as a string that you pass to `new RegExp()` like:

```
new RegExp('(^|\\s)a\\d')
```

...but doing it with a string is more hassle because you have to escape any backslashes in the string (notice in my example they're doubled?), so I'd only do that when building a regex out of variables such as when it needs to include data entered by the user.

Comment: Thank you as well. This even seems more bullet proof, but I do not know why, but in string (and other similar as well) "question_text a2" gives me your solution "false" but test()ing for /a\d/ gives me the correct answer "true"

Comment: The string `"question_text a2"` gives `true` for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4bDXf/ (I tested several such examples before posting my answer.)

Comment: sorry :) solved :)... i forget to remove splitting the string before test()ing it, so the commas messed it up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( element.prop('class')[0]=='a' && !isNaN(element.prop('class').substring(1)) )
```

May be, I guess, faster than any regular expression

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I learn by running into problems and unknown functions (and I haven't gone through this one yet), may I just ask for a short "into-human-language" translation of what is after "&&"?

Comment: OK, get it. Was not that hard to understand at all :). The problem with that would be (I did not mention it in my request), that I would be dependent on position of that class. My elements have multiple other classes and can even have multiple "a*"-classes. But otherwise thank you as well.